# how to get the axis value when I click on a cursor in highstock(high charts)?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using high stock API reference.

I want to know Where can I get the axis value when I click on a cursor?

Please help me!

Answer (score 4):

If you use Highstock then you can get x value (time in miliseconds) and use Highcharts.dateFormat() which return data in appropriate format. (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#highcharts.dateFormat())

http://jsfiddle.net/NX4KN/

```
 plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            alert('Date: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',this.x) + ', value: ' + this.y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can user series `click` event:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click/)

```
series: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
        events: {
             click: function() {
                 alert ('Category: '+ this.category +', value: '+ this.y);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a demo from highcharts but I meant highstock. I found this example from highcharts : [link]http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/events-setextremes/